# Trigger a Custom Function Every X Hours in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am looking to trigger code every 1 Hour in AWS.

The code should: Parse through a list of zip codes, fetch data for each of the zip codes, store that data somewhere in AWS.

- Is there a specific AWS service would I use for parsing through the list of zip codes and call the api for each zip code? Would this be Lambda?
- How could I schedule this service to run every X hours? Do I have to use another AWS Service to call my Lambda function (assuming that's the right answer to #1)?
- Which AWS service could I use to store this data?

I tried looking up different approaches and services in AWS. I found I could write serverless code in Lambda which made me think it would be the answer to my first question. Then I tried to look into how that could be ran every x time, but that's where I was struggling to know if I could still use Lambda for that. Then knowing where my options were to store the data. I saw that Glue may be an option, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Seems like what you want is something similar to a cron job.  
Depending on the data dynamodb could be used to store the data.

Comment: That makes sense! Do you know if Amazon EventBridge could do the cron job portion?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have the AWS knowledge to answer that.

Comment: You have been more than helpful, thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Lambda to run your code (as long as the total run time is [less than 15 minutes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution)).

**You can use [Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) to trigger the Lambda every 1 hour.**

> Which AWS service could I use to store this data?

That depends on the format of the data and how you will subsequently use it. Some options are

- [Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) for key-value, noSQL data
- [Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_AuroraOverview.html) for relational data
- [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) for object storage

If you choose S3, you can still do SQL-like queries on the data using [Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html)